# not able to render all images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can retrieve 3 images (apple.jpg, banana.jpg, kiwi.jpg) using the JS Fetch API: promises fulfilled and blob created but can render only one the kiwi.jpg image and not the remaining two jpg images maybe because of overlapping . Kindly advise any concepts I am missing and help.

Note: All the above mentioned .jpg images are present in the same location as the HTML and JS code.

```js
const myImage = document.querySelector(".someImage");
var x=["apple.jpg","banana.jpg","kiwi.jpg"]
x.forEach((x1)=>{ 
myRequest = new Request(x1)
fetch(myRequest).then (async response => {
myBlob=await response.blob() 
objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob)
myImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob)
URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL)
} 
)}
)
```

```css
img{
display:inline
}
```

```html
 <!--below apple.jpg image should appear -->
 <img class="someImage" src</img>
 <!--below banana.jpg image should appear -->
 <img src=" " />
 <!--below kiwi.jpg image should appear -->
 <img src=" " />
```

Comment: could you just set the image sources?

Comment: you mean i loop the .someImage variable inside the document.querySelector(".someImage")  function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to handle this as blobs and create your own url reference then you can do this. I created an array of placeholder paths for the purposes of this snippet. You need to grab all the image elements and use the index as a relationship between the array of paths and array of elements. Also you can't destroy the URL object afterwards if you want it to stay. I'll include a way to just change the src as well though.

```js
const myImages = document.querySelectorAll("img");
//const imagePaths = ["./apple.jpg", "./banana.jpg", "./kiwi.jpg"];
const placeholderUrl = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5c9a8b9f51420f0a4f548de5a6e39bd3?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG";
const imagePaths = Array(3).fill(placeholderUrl);
imagePaths.forEach((path, i) => { 
    fetch(path).then(response => response.blob()).then(blob => {
        const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        myImages[i].src = objectURL;
        //URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
    });
})
```

```css
img {
  display:inline
}
```

```html
<!--below apple.jpg image should appear -->
 <img class="someImage" />
 <!--below banana.jpg image should appear -->
 <img src=" " />
 <!--below kiwi.jpg image should appear -->
 <img src=" " />
```

Here we just add the src attribute to the elements. No need to fetch as a blob or anything of the sort.

```js
const myImages = document.querySelectorAll("img");
//const imagePaths = ["./apple.jpg", "./banana.jpg", "./kiwi.jpg"];
const placeholderUrl = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5c9a8b9f51420f0a4f548de5a6e39bd3?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG";
const imagePaths = Array(3).fill(placeholderUrl);
imagePaths.forEach((path, i) => { 
    myImages[i].src = path;
})
```

```html
 <!--below apple.jpg image should appear -->
 <img class="someImage" />
 <!--below banana.jpg image should appear -->
 <img src=" " />
 <!--below kiwi.jpg image should appear -->
 <img src=" " />
```

Comment: if possible give me the blob way reason as images may be fetched async

Comment: @Charles the top half of my answer is the blob way. You should be able to fetch a source async too, but if you have something that generates a blob on the backend you can use the first half to accomplish it no problem.

Comment: for documentation purposes,you can delete <img class="someImage" />and replace with the generic<img src=" " /> in your html snippet as .someImage no longer needed

Comment: and the JS Snippet to:
const myImages = document.querySelectorAll("img");
const imagePaths = ["./potato.jpg", "./banana.jpg", "./kiwi.jpg"];
imagePaths.forEach((path, i) => { 
    fetch(path).then(response => response.blob()).then(blob => {
        const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        myImages[i].src = objectURL;
       // URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
    });
})

Comment: the answer from @async-await is of top quality

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are only updating the first `<img />` tag since it is the only tag with a class attribute.
Here are a few extra recommendations:

- Make sure you close your HTML tags correctly, either with a `</tag>` or a `/>`, this can lead to unexpected and inconsistent behavior in different web browsers
- Make sure you don't have extra brackets in your code. In some cases, this will not be an issue, but in other cases, it can cause a lot of headache!
  Here is a suggestion on how you can change your code:

```
<!--below apple.jpg image should appear -->
 <img class="appleImage" src />
 <!--below banana.jpg image should appear -->
 <img class="bananaImage" src />
 <!--below kiwi.jpg image should appear -->
 <img class="kiwiImage" src />
```

and change your javascript to something like this:

```
var x=["apple","banana","kiwi"]
x.forEach((x1)=>{ 
    myRequest = new Request(x1 + ".jpg")
    fetch(myRequest).then (async response => {
        myBlob=await response.blob() 
        objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob)
        const myImage = document.querySelector("." + x1 + "Image");
        myImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob)
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL)
    } 
)}
```